# サーバのエラーログの確認方法

Tags: php, wordpress

ワードプレスでサイト作成をしています。
エラーが出てしまい、エラー内容は、固定ページや投稿ページが表示されづに
真っ白な画面が表示されるものです。

このエラーを解決すべく、サーバのエラーログの確認をしたいのですが、
初心者で、サーバの表示方法などがわかりません、どうしたら確認できますか？

サイトはローカルです、
VirtualBoxと、Vagrantで、KUSANAGIを使用しています。

Comment: エラーの確認方法とありますが、利用しているOSやソフトウェアまたその設定によってログの場所は様々です。考えるに、OS、Webサーバ、PHP,KUSANAGIそれぞれエラーが出力されている可能性があります。vagrantで起動したサーバにログインしてどのような設定になっているか確認はできますか？仮想環境の提供者に確認するのも一つの手です

Answer (score 0):

すいません、ただ、固定ページのファイルがなかっただけだと思います、
今は最初からやり直してできるようになりました。